# int 21h doesn't work

Tags: arrays, search, assembly, printing

this code should return the index of the position of 'ricerca' in the array 'vett'; if it isn't present it should return -1;

```
dim equ 8
.model small
.stack
.data
        vett db 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
        ricerca db 4
.code
.startup
        mov cx, dim
        mov di, 0
        mov bh, ricerca

lab:    cmp vett[di], bh
        jz lab2

        sub cx, 2
        cmp cx, 0
        jnz lab

        mov byte ptr dl, -1
    jmp fine

lab2:   mov dx, di
    jmp fine
fine:   mov ah, 2
    int 21h

.exit
end
```

why doesn't it print anything on the screen?

Comment: How are you assembling and running it?

Comment: In addition to the other comments here, you should have | mov ax,4c00h  |  int 21h | just before | end | to exit the program properly.

Answer (score 0):

As described [here](http://spike.scu.edu.au/~barry/interrupts.html#ah02), DOS function 2 outputs a character in `dl`. In your code, the value in `dl` seems to be either `0` after `mov dx, di` or `255` after `mov byte ptr dl, -1`.

Both these characters (0 and 255) are invisible.

I think you can get a better impression on what is going on by redirecting standard output to a file, and looking at a hex-dump of that file.

Comment: what debugger can i use to view the result of the operation without making output? can you recommend me an IDE or a debugger? Turbo Debugger doesn't work on my pc

Comment: I use Turbo Debugger and the standard DOS debugger `debug.com`, both in DOSBox

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't make sense. There are a lot of things wrong here.

1. You are not modifying `di` anywhere in the loop, so you are examining the first element in the array every time.
2. You are subtracting 2 from `cx` every time through the loop, so you will only end up looping through half of the array.
3. You are treating `dl` as a byte pointer and writing to it when your search fails.
4. You are printing the result as a character, not a number.
5. You are writing 16-bit x86 assembly for a DOS environment. This is not a platform which anybody has seriously used for anything (besides bootloaders) in decades.

   If you want to learn assembly, learn 32-bit (or 64-bit) assembly for a modern system. DOS was a very different place.

Comment: what program can I use to assemble it in 32-bit or 64-bit? (now i can't do it becouse I use tasm)